# Example for procedures with INOUT parameters in Oracle, PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle9i

How can I use IN OUT parameter in a procedure. I want to give a parameter as both input and get the same out put? can i have an example for this?

Answer (score 4):

Do this in SQL Plus:

```
set serverout on

declare
  l_val varchar2(30) := 'hello world';
  procedure myproc (p_val in out varchar2) is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('p_val was ' || p_val);
    p_val := 'something else';
  end;
begin
   myproc(l_val);
   dbms_output.put_line('l_val is now ' || l_val);
end;
/
```

You should see the output:

```
p_val was hello world
l_val is now something else
```

Comment: @Bhanu, did you type `set serverout on`?

Answer (score 1):

See the Oracle PL/SQL documentation, section "Specifying Subprogram Parameter Modes":

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#895